# Building profile in user model for registration, is user_id in attr_accessible big mistake?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, attr-accessible

Using devise as my authentication system I would like to build my profile on user registration.

I read many topics about this on SO, and decided to take the approach of building the profile within the model:

#### profile.rb

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  attr_accessible :user_id, # FIXME This is secure?
end
```

#### user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  devise ...

  has_one :profile
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :profile

  def build_profile
    Profile.create(:user_id => id)
  end

end
```

My two questions are:

Is having the user_id in attr_accessible dangerous (mass-assignement)?

Did I have to put my profile creation in a controller (registration create) using a transaction? (Here if my profile fails to build I have still a user record)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is having the user_id in attr_accessible dangerous (mass-assignement)?

yes it is, you should avoid adding foreign keys to attr_accessible most of the time, although there's scenario that it's ok to use (if the association publicly accessible like countries for example) or if you override the setter and do some kind of check..

> Did I have to put my profile creation in a controller (registration create) using a transaction? (Here if my profile fails to build I have still a user record)

just add `validates_associated :profile` in User model and maybe also `validates :profile, presence: true` (kinda forgot if validates_associated allow nil or not)